# sql query for dividing equally

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written this sql query

```
update temp_calpoints1  
set perwet = (select perwet
              from process 
              where processid = temp_calpoints1.processid)
```

As of now it updates 10 percent for every user as below.

```
orderid            processid          uid            ordervalue            perwet
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
1                     1                1               10000              10
1                     1                2               10000              10
1                     1                3               10000              10
1                     2                1               10000              10
1                     2                2               10000              10
1                     3                1               10000              10
```

I want that if more than 1 users are involved in 1 process in same order it should divide the percent equally

That means it must insert like this

```
orderid        processid             uid         ordervalue          perwet
------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
1                    1                1               10000             3.33 
1                     1               2               10000             3.33
1                     1               3               10000             3.33
1                     2               1               10000             5.00
1                     2               2               10000             5.00
1                     3               1               10000            10.00
```

Any  idea?

Structure of tables

```
     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[temp_calpoints1](
     [orderid] [int] NULL,
     [processid] [int] NULL,
     [uid] [int] NULL,
     [ordervalue] [bigint] NULL,
     [perwet] [float] NULL
     ) ON [PRIMARY]



     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[process](
     [processid] [float] NULL,
     [processdesc] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
     [perwet] [int] NULL
     ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try like this

```
update t set perwet = ((select perwet from process where processid = t.processid)  
/(select count(uid) from temp_calpoints1 group by orderid,processid having processid = 
t.processid AND orderid=t.orderid )) from temp_calpoints1 t;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ab51/19)

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 't'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '/'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Which database you are using? Try using table name directly instead of alias if it can solve your problem

Comment: Check the edited answer. This runs syntactically. See whether it's functionally right.

Comment: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: This will return only one row in subquery.Edited answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26523/discussion-between-pranav-kevadiya-and-user1758480)

Comment: Hey..Updated the answer if you have missed that..check http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ab51/19

Answer (score 0):

```
update temp_calpoints1  set perwet = (select perwet/count(uid)
  from process 
  where 
  processid=temp_calpoints1.processid group by uid)
```

Comment: it is giving

Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Answer (score 0):

```
update temp_calpoints1 set perwet = processcallpoints.perwet
from (select MAX(process.perwet) / COUNT(1) perwet from temp_calpoints1 inner join process on temp_calpoints1.processid = process.processid group by process.processid) processcallpoints
```

Incidentally, you can't have 3.33 because the column type is int, therfore you'll get 3

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2631/2)**

```
UPDATE temp_calpoints1  
SET perwet = (SELECT p.perwet/(SELECT CASE WHEN count(*) = 0
                                      THEN 1 ELSE count(*) * 1.00  END
                             FROM temp_calpoints1 t2
                             WHERE t2.processid = temp_calpoints1.processid)
              FROM  process p 
              WHERE p.processid = temp_calpoints1.processid)
```

Result:

```
| ORDERID | PROCESSID | UID | ORDERVALUE | PERWET |
---------------------------------------------------
|       1 |         1 |   1 |      10000 |   3.33 | 
|       1 |         1 |   2 |      10000 |   3.33 |
|       1 |         1 |   3 |      10000 |   3.33 |
```